# When I substract two datetime object in python it is considering only time not taking day

Tags: python, datetime

I have two date time objects

```
`statrt_time` and `end_time`
```

my code is

```
if self.book_from and  self.book_to:
        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        s = datetime.strptime(self.book_from,fmt)   #start date
        e = datetime.strptime(self.book_to,fmt)   #end date
        diff = e - s

        total_seconds=diff.seconds
        time_diff = (total_seconds/3600.0)
        no_of_units = (time_diff/4)
        if(e<s):
            self.units = 0
        else:
            self.units = math.ceil(no_of_units)
```

Here when I subtract time within the same day it is giving the correct difference. But when the day is changed, it is not calculating the day difference but only giving time difference. How can I add day difference also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) instead of `seconds`.

`timedelta.seconds` just shows "second" part of the difference, while `total_seconds()` shows the duration of the difference in seconds. See [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36589675/895932) for more details.

So, use this:

```
total_seconds=diff.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 3):

`total_seconds` is a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object which stores the difference between two datetimes using three fields - `days`, `seconds` and `miliseconds`. Your snippet just uses the `seconds` attributes instead of the entire difference. The [`total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method takes care of this for you and returns, well, the total number of seconds between two datatimes.

Answer (score 0):

I got another way of doing.. BUT A WORK AROUND..

```
if self.book_from and  self.book_to:
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    s = datetime.strptime(self.book_from,fmt)   #start date
    e = datetime.strptime(self.book_to,fmt)   #end date
    diff = e - s
    days=diff.days// convert difference to day instead of seconds//
    days_seconds=0
    if(days>0): //Checking whether the difference exceeds a day//
        days_seconds=days*24*3600 //If so convert it to seconds//

    total_seconds=diff.seconds+days_seconds
    time_diff = (total_seconds/3600.0)
```

Comment: This method will give the true difference if there is no difference in hour, since essentially you are measuring the difference in the day part and the second part only.

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes, it would work because timedelta stores the difference only in day and seconds. So internally the `total_seconds()` method is doing what you are doing here.